# filter Dropdown with max values,min values and step values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a drop-down list with numbers comers a minimum values to a fixed maximun values and a fixed step
for example min = 1 max = 8 step = 2
The choices in the drop down list are : 1,2,4,6,8 
These three indicators are in the table "Project"

```
class Project(models.Model):
    min = models.IntegerField(default='4')
    max = models.IntegerField(default='10')
    Note = models.IntegerField(default='1')
```

The value selected in the dropdown will be storing in another table "Detail"

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    pourcentage = models.IntegerField()
```

I do not know how to build the drop-down in the form and view with all the data mentioned before 
could someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the `choices` option - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices

```
def generate_choices(start, stop, step):
    return [(i, i) for i in range(start, stop, step)]

min = models.IntegerField(default='4', choices=generate_choices(1, 10, 2))
```

OK the function generating the choices itself looks a bit odd, but you get the point :)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I think you have misunderstood the problem, I want to create a form with a drop down list with numbers ranging from min to max  with step by step, and the value chosen in the form will be stored in pourcentage

Comment: ok then instead of `min` in my answer, use the `pourcentage` field. If you want the `Detail` object to be connected to the `Project` object, and have the `pourcentage` values generated based on the min, max, step fields in the latter, then you'll need a foreign key field and then dynamically re-generate the `pourcentage` field based on the corresponding values.. which is doable but something you should work through yourself :)